# Highcharts dynamicly update chart from csv file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv, highcharts

I have been studying the  [dynamic spline jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/)
 on highcharts documentation page. There, they use `Math.random()` to update the data and add it to the series.

From the doc, I also know how to load typical [csv files](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module) all at once (or using excellent code from [rapid highcharts](https://github.com/thombergs/rapid-highcharts/tree/master/dashboard-app) :

```
function parseCSVData(csvFile) {
var data = [] 
var lines = csvFile.split("\n")
$.each(lines, function (lineNumber, line) {
    var fields = line.split(",");
    if (fields.length == 2){
        var timestamp = Date.parse(fields[0])
        var value = parseFloat(fields[1]);
        data.push([timestamp, value])
    }
})
return data}
```

)

What I want to do is to:

- read one line of the csv file
- update the chart
- pause for 1 sec
- redo above till the end of the file

and hence mimic a realtime application.

However, I can't simply put it under the `event : load` since there is no way to track which lines have been read previously. 
The examples where they pull data in realtime all use some sort of api or websocket, which is too advanced for me and not usable in my case anyway.
Say my csv file looks like this: ([sample.csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28390827/sampleData.csv))

`t observed
1   19
2   12
3   28
4   17
5   85
6   22
7   86
8   16
9   90
10  93
11  39
12  96
13  42
14  74
15  100
16  22
17  41
18  32`

Is there a way to perform the above steps in a relatively easy way? [my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2ph7jap/)

Comment: can you do it like in the spline example? with the settimeout they have there, they dont use math.random to update the data, they use it to generate random data, the setTimeout is what updates it

 can you show us how your chart looks right now in a fiddle?

Comment: They use `setInterval` to generate new data and append it to the series every second. I can't do that here since I need to track which lines have been read so far. any code that goes under the `event : load` would not be able to keep a reference of previous actions. I don't have a working fiddle really, but this is the closest to it : https://jsfiddle.net/f2ph7jap/

Comment: You could start with parsing all CSV data into an array. Next, that array will be iterated in `setInterval` until all array is added, then clear the interval. Define array and iterator outside interval function, so it will be accessible across all iterations.

Comment: @KacperMadej Thanks for the workflow. My js skills are rather limited, would it be possible for you to add the outline of it in my jsfiddle?

Comment: @Pep Yes, I added a demo as an answer - if something is not clear feel free to ask in comment of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you will iterate over parsed data array using iterator defined outside of `setInterval`, then you could load point on each iteration. When iterator reaches length of available data you could clear the interval using `clearInterval`.

For purpose of JSFiddle demo let's load CSV data from HTML.

Example based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/qkxda04n/

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. A bit unrelated, but is it possible to remove Zoom levels and "From" "To", from this?

Comment: @Pep Yes, just set `rangeSelector: {enabled: false},` - example: http://jsfiddle.net/qkxda04n/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about maintaining a variable for the next array index that you need to plot?

```
setInterval(function () {
    if(window.nextIndex===undefined){
        window.nextIndex=0;
    }else{
        window.nextIndex++;
    }                        
    series.addPoint(data[window.nextIndex], true, true);
}, 1000);
```